# iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30mW - not working

Tags: wireless, adapter

I would like to increase the power of my wireless adapter but when I enter

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30mW`

in the terminal and then check with `iwconfig` I can see that the txpower is still what it used to be before I tried changing it.

My network controller is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

And here is the `ifconfig` output if that helps:

```
wlan0   
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:19:34:f5:39:08  
inet addr:192.168.1.129  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::8219:34ff:fef5:3908/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:4474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:3726 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:2361924 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:520175 (520.1 KB)
```

However, just as a side note, `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` is working, for switching `wlan0`'s power management off.

Comment: what does sudo iwlist txpower wlan0 say?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@wie5Ooma, Is right about violating the law. but about the answering the question.
As it goes:

> **WARNING** Removing all restrictions is illegal in the United States.
>   This is only for educational reasons, and if you choose to
>   apply it and break the law, then that is your choice and not mine.
>   Please be careful putting this into action.
>   This is for Education purpose only!

- First we gonna need to use some packages:

  - `python-m2crypto`
  - `libgcrypt11`
  - `libgcrypt11-dev`
  - `libnl-dev`
- To check if they're installed:

  ```
  dpkg -s python-m2crypto libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev libnl-dev
  ```
- If not, to install:

  ```
  apt-get install python-m2crypto libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev libnl-dev
  ```
- Now, you'll need wireless regulatory database CRDA, and `wireless-regdb` tools to build the database read by CRDA to provide regulatory domains to the Linux kernel.

  - [CRDA](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda)
  - [Wireless-regdb](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/wireless-regdb/)
- Navigate to the download folder and unzip the files.

Now here is the interesting part. This is where we actually get to change the regulations. Change your directory to the `wireless-regdb` folder, and in there you will find a file called `db.txt`. This is the file we will edit. Let's take a quick look at it:

```
more db.txt
```

[image: more of db.txt]

- Now let's take a look at a few things here. Look at what I underlined above. First, let's notice the first entry (`country 00`) which is the world regulatory domain and this is applied before all else. So when you turn on your BackTrack system, the world domain is applied to you first and then you can change regulatory domains from there to other countries like country **AM**.

The second thing I underlined, which can go a max of **20 dBm**, the third thing I underlined, on the **2.4ghz** band. If you wanna change how high you can go, that is the number you want to change.

- For example, let's change Bolivia's rules*

  nano db.txt
  Scroll down until you find country BO.
  [image]
- Look at what I highlighted. This is the number we want to change.

If your card can go up to **2000 mW**, then you would change that number to **33**, which stands for **33 dBm**, which is approximately **2000 mW**. The number you are replacing is in decibels.

I am not sure about your card, some wireless cards like the [AWUS036NHA](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&es_sm=93&output=search&tbm=shop&q=AWUS036NHA%202000mw&oq=AWUS036NHA%202000mw&gs_l=products-cc.3...8067.11509.0.11601.7.1.0.6.0.0.68.68.1.1.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.products-cc..7.0.0.S1MD24gqfXw) may be stuck in a country and cannot be changed from that country. In that case, Find out which country your card believes it is in and change that country's configurations.

> Quick [DECIBEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) understanding:
>
> Every **10** decibels is a **10X** increase in power starting from **1 dBm** equal
>   to **1mW**... **10 dBm** equals **10 mW**, **20 dBm** equals **100 mW**, **30 dBm** equals
>   **1000 mW**, and so on. Quick [DECIBEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) understanding:

Every 10 decibels is a 10X increase in power starting from 1 dBm equal to 1mW... 10 dBm equals 10 mW, 20 dBm equals 100 mW, 30 dBm equals 1000 mW, and so on. Every 3 decibels is approximately double that of the prior power, so 30 dBm is 1000 mW, if we add 3 dBm, then we can double the power such that 33 dBm is about equal to 2000 mW.
Every **3** decibels is approximately double that of

> the prior power, so **30 dBm** is **1000 mW**, if we add **3 dBm**, then we can
>   double the power such that **33 dBm** is about equal to **2000 mW**.

Now, Pay attention.

[image]

Notice now I changed the number to **33**. When we are finished here, when I change my regulatory domain to **BO**, i can set my `txpower` to **33**.

- Now save the changes when you are done by pressing first, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and finally, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you need to swap our old regulatory file with the one you downloaded. While still in the `wireless-regdb` directory, just enter the command `make`.

You'll notice you have some new files now in that directory. This is good.
your `regulatory.bin` file in this directory now needs to be replaced with the old one.

First navigate to the authentic `regulatory.db`'s location.

```
cd /usr/lib/crda
```

And let's also make a backup of the old one just in case (Recommended).

```
mv regulatory.bin regulatoryOLD.bin
```

Now let's bring in the new one. Go back to your directory of our new regulatory.bin and let's copy it over and verify it's there.

```
cd {path to your new regulatory.bin}
cp regulatory.bin /usr/lib/crda/regulatory.bin
cd /usr/lib/crda
ls
```

**Validating**
Now we have our new regulatory.db, but it is not valid yet. Go back to the wireless-regdb directory and you'll notice you have some files with an extension of .pem. Copy ALL files ending with a `.pem` into your downloaded `crda` directory in `pubkeys`. These are the files that CRDA will use to check if `regulatory.bin` is valid.

```
cd ~/Desktop/wireless-regdb-2013.10.11
cp root.key.pub.pem ~/Desktop/crda-1.1.3/pubkeys/root.key.pub.pem
cp linville.key.pub.pem
~/Desktop/crda-1.1.3/pubkeys/linville.key.pub.pem
```

And verify:

```
cd ~/Desktop/crda-1.1.3/pubkeys
ls
```

Finally, Now go up a directory from where you are back to the downloaded `crda` directory and install this puppy.

```
cd ..
make
make install
```

You should be seeing something like that.
[image]

If so, reboot: `sudo reboot`

After reboot:

```
iw reg set BO
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 33
```

Comment: john_s has a stability problem with a Intel card and not a problem with the wireless power (a X-Y problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) However, your answer is the best answer for the question, it will work only for high power antennas, but your answer deserves the bounty.

Comment: @j0h said below: The Bolivia trick should only work if the db is less than 30. If you look at the bolivia settings, the limit is 30. if you want to switch to bolivia, and go higher, you need to edit and recompile the database that contains the regional settings. why you wouldn't use US, I don't know, there is a US in the database. try this: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/ youll need to find the actual source for crda though. I found this page in the man page for https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory#crda

Comment: Where is the regulatory.db file?  On ubuntu 16.04 I don't even have the /usr/lib/crda folder.  I found it in the /lib/crda folder.

Comment: It never created a linville.key.pub.pem key for me.

Comment: I am trying to lower the txpower (to test), and it still remains unchanged to 20dBm. Any ideas?

Comment: @chefarov, I think the regulatory have changed a while after this answer, however there is another solution, I may be able to share when I am back home, it’s hard to do so for a cellphone.

Comment: A small flaw: 0 dBm is 1mW, not 1 dBm as the answer says. Despite, this answer is very detailed and fabulous!

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to boost the transmission power, however that's subject to limitations both legally and technically. Wireless transmissions observe CRDA rules which put simply is a list that describes what maximum transmission power is allowed. Your device/operating system has a country code therefore knows what to do. If there is no countrycode it operates at generic values that are always safe to use.

There's more: Certain cards are even technically limited. They've an in built fixed country code and are constructed such that they can't use a higher power whatever you try.

I have an Intel wireless card too and Tx power is always at 16 whatever I try to increase it.

Comment: Hi wie5Ooma, essentially, I don't want to violate law and I'm not particularly aiming for setting the wireless adapter to 30wM. However, under Windows the signal strength that is shown and also the felt speed of the connection is much better and more stable. 

Any other hints on what I could try?

Comment: Now you're slightly shifting the question towards the realm of opinion-based. Without any numerical evidence I really can't tell if there's any difference between Windows and Linux because I don't use Windows. I have to think a little more about this. On a side note: are you aware that you're writing wM instead of mW? So it should be first a small M followed by a capital W spelling mW which stands for milliWatt.

Answer (score 3):

This can be because you are in a country  with a limiting law. You can increase the power beyond your local limit but this will likely be **breaking the law**. This is only for **high power antennas**.

#### METHOD 1:

Open terminal and copy paste the following commands:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iw reg set BO
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If above method gives the following error then go for METHOD 2.

```
Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B26) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

#### METHOD 2:

Open terminal and copy paste the following commands:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iw reg set BO
iwconfig wlan0 channel 13
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

#### SOURCE: [This page](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/10/27/how-to-increase-tx-power-signal-strength-of-wifi/)

Comment: Oh, I meant sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30mW. Even when I do sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 20mW instead of 30mW, it's not working.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't works?

Comment: @ Helio: thanks for getting back. For both methods step 2 `sudo iw reg set B0` produces the following error message:

    not a valid ISO/IEC 3166-1 alpha2 
    Special non-alpha2 usable entries:
    00 World Regulatory domain

Comment: @ Helio: I was thinking that I could see whether it's working by simply entering iwconfig and checking the number behind Tx-Power=NUMBER HERE dBm

Comment: It is `BO` with O, as BOlivia, not B-zero

Comment: Okay, however step 2 method 1 results in `Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B26) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted.`

Comment: Step 2 method 2 results in `Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04): SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.`

Comment: Keep in mind that all the commands need to be ran as `root`

Comment: Yes, I was running all commands as root.

Comment: I edited my post, try now the second method.

Comment: What is the name of your interface?

Comment: The name of the network adapter is 'Intel Corporation Wireless 7260' (rev 73). At least this is shown to me when `lspci` in the terminal.

Comment: I have tried method two again, but get the following error message when trying to change the channel (step 3): 

The name of the network adapter is 'Intel Corporation Wireless 7260' (rev 73). At least this is shown to me when `lspci` in the terminal.

Comment: Interestingly, when doing `iwlist wlan0 modulation` I get 'wlan0 unknown modulation information'.

Comment: When I say *the name of your interface* I'm refering to `wlan0` `wlan1` `wlan256`... ;-)

Comment: The name of the interface is `wlan0`

Comment: I thing that a Intel laptop wifi adapter cannot reach 1W of power, however, you can try to omit the `iwconfig wlan0 channel 13` step.

Comment: Even if I skip step `iwconfig wlan0 channel 13` at the next step `iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30` I'm getting the 8B26 error message again. ..Hmm, seems like I will have to give up. But on the other hand, my wifi under Windows (same computer) certainly establishes a more stable wifi connection.

Comment: And do you think that the stability of the connection is related to the power?

Comment: Any other ideas that could be a potential culprit for having a weaker connection in Ubuntu than in MS Win?

Comment: I've made a new answer for what I think that can solve your wireless stability.

Answer (score 2):

Type these commands, they will enable AGG TX and can greatly improve the performance of wireless N networks. [This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630) says that performance dropped by 85% without the use of `11n_disable=8`

```
sudo rmmod iwlmvm
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

Now, try your computer as you would do normally. If the signal is still low, this solution is probably not a solution for your case. In this case, just restart the computer to revert the change you did.  If it becomes normal and fast, do it permanently by typing the following line in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf
```

A file will be opened (it may not exist before that). At the end of the file, paste the following line then save:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

After saving, just quit and reboot.

---

If this doesn't work, replace `11n_disable=8` with `11n_disable=1` and repeat procedure.

Comment: Hi Helio, thanks for this. When entering `sudo rmmod iwlwifi` I'm getting the following error message: `rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwlmvm` Shall I deactivate iwlmvm?

Comment: I fail to see what this answer has to do with the original question. This '11n_disable' trick does not improve signal strength and on 11n networks effectively impairs the connection because you're disabling N-speed capabilities here thereby limiting speed to 11g, being it 54Mb/s instead of 150 or depending on your equipment even 300 Mb/s.

Comment: @wie5Ooma you have reason, however it will improve the connection stability, and about the speed, I think that will not be a great loss, however, is john_s which will have the last word ;-)

Comment: @john_s yes, you may remove `iwlmvm` if it's loaded. Use this command: `sudo rmmod iwlmvm`. I updated my post.

Comment: Hi Helio, I entered all three commands with getting any error message. However, wifi signal stability and strength didn't improve.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more. I'll open a bounty.

Comment: The Bolivia trick should only work if the db is less than 30. If you look at the bolivia settings, the limit is 30. if you want to switch to bolivia, and go higher, you need to edit and recompile the database that contains the regional settings. why you wouldn't use US, I don't know, there is a US in the database.
try this:http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/
youll need to find the actual source for crda though. I found this page in the man page for crda:https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory#crda

Answer (score 1):

Hello I personally use Kali linux 2 with an ALPHA network card awus036nh and I use method 1 to change the tx card's power.

For those of you having some trouble with **BO** reg set , try with **GY** reg set instead. It's fully functional for me whereas it fails with BO ! Hope it helps!

```
ifconfig wlan1 down
iw reg set GY
iwconfig wlan1 txpower 30
ifconfig wlan1 up
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.10, crda is under `/lib/crda/`.
In order to compile the new 'crda', do:

```
sudo su
cp -r /lib/crda /usr/lib/crda
cd /usr/lib/crda
mv regulatory.bin regulatory.bin.bak
cd {path to your new regulatory.bin}
cp regulatory.bin /usr/lib/crda/regulatory.bin
```

Then move the [generated *.pem files](https://askubuntu.com/a/605511/448428) to your downloaded crda directory:

```
cd {path to downloads folder}/wireless-regdv-YYYY.MM.DD
cp {path to your new regulatory.bin}/*.pem pubkeys/
make
make install
```

Now copy the crda folder back from '/usr/lib/crda' to its default path in Ubuntu 16:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/crda /lib/
```

`sudo reboot` and `iw reg set {country-code}`.

I've used this method to set my wifi to use the frequency ranges and legal power-levels allocated to the amateur radio service of my country. This is **restricted to licensed amateur radio operators only.**